# Copy file from one path to another

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, file, copy

A am fetching a file name and file path from the database as described below:

```
        msSQL = " select file_name,file_path FROM myTable where file_id='F012'"
        Dim Reader = myCommonFun.GetDataReader(msSQL)
        Dim file_path As String = Nothing
        If Reader.HasRows = True Then
            Reader.Read()
            Dim file_Name as string = Reader.Item("file_name").ToString
            Dim file_path = Reader.Item("file_path").ToString
        End If
```

Now what i need is that i want to take the file in the path returned by the query and copy the same file to another location. for that am using the snippet as :

```
Dim destinationFile as string = Server.MapPath("../uploaded/" & file_Name)
File.Copy(file_path , destinationFile, True)
```

**but it wont result as expected, what am doing wrong? how can i achieve the target?**

**Updates**

- in `File.Copy(file_path , destinationFile, True)`
- file_path : `D:\new\data\me.doc`
- destinationFile : `D:\web\mypro\uploaded\me.doc`

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: no error and warning and also nothing is copying

Comment: What is value of file_path in DB ?Provide an example.

Comment: see nupdates in the question

Answer (score 2):

You should combine file_path with file_Name with extension
Try below code

```
Dim destinationFile as string = Server.MapPath("../uploaded/" & file_Name)
File.Copy(file_path , destinationFile, True)
```

Change to

```
Dim destinationFile as string = Server.MapPath("../uploaded/" & file_Name)
file_path =file_path &"\\"& file_Name
File.Copy(file_path , destinationFile, True)
```

Comment: i got the paths correctly but it doesnot perform copy

Comment: Please check write permission on destination location.